# Why does rails.bat work but rails does not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

When attempting to create a new Ruby on Rails app in Windows the command

```
rails new test_app
```

returns an error

```
'rails' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program 
or batch  file
```

but the command

```
rails.bat new test_app
```

works just fine. I have added the ..\ruby\bin directory to my PATH variable but it doesn't seem to change anything. A similar problem occurs for all other 'rails' commands as well as for 'rake' vs 'rake.bat'.

Running `type rails.bat` returns:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
@"ruby.exe" "C:/_LOCALdata/Ruby192/bin/rails" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
GOTO :EOF
:WinNT
@"ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*
```

Comment: Did you read rails.bat to see what it does differently from what you type on the command line?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Can you clarify?

Comment: From a command prompt (as in `C:>`, type `type rails.bat` and press Enter. Read what's on the screen. How is that different from what you're typing yourself when you try to do it manually? Also, I note you added `../ruby/bin` to your PATH... You do realize on Windows a \ and not a / is used for the path separator?

Comment: `type rails.bat` returns the following:

@ECHO OFF
IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
@"ruby.exe" "C:/_LOCALdata/Ruby192/bin/rails" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
GOTO :EOF
:WinNT
@"ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*

Comment: I'm aware of windows vs *nix conventions but I figured most people here were uses of the later. Post updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your updated question I can assume that PATHEXT, the environment variable responsible for knowing files to be executed without extensions is missing .BAT from it.

To confirm, please do `SET PATHEXT` on a new command prompt and see the output, the result should be a semi-colon separated values that include `.EXE`, `.BAT`, `.COM` and perhaps `.RB`

If `PATHEXT` is empty or do not contain `.BAT` in it, that could explain why is not working.

Depending on your version of Windows, the installation of RubyInstaller might have caused that, in which case I recommend uninstall and verify the environment variables to see if it get restored.

Then try to install it again.

See [this thread on RubyInstaller](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyinstaller/browse_thread/thread/2b2007a659390a6) about this.

Comment: Already am using cmd.exe. Have never used either of the programs you reference. problem exists in cmd.exe

Comment: Please provide the complete error you're receiving so we can better diagnose the problem. Update the question with that information.

Answer (score 0):

you have to download railsinstaller for windows this would help you solve all conflicts 
download it from [rubyforge](http://rubyforge.org/projects/railsinstaller/)

Comment: Ummm... If rails.bat works, obviously rails is installed. This is a path issue or something, and downloading an installer isn't the answer. You might want to delete this before you start collecting down votes and losing rep.

Comment: dude u using ruby on windows dont forget. i have had this problem before. trust me and just do as i said. it helps a lot when it comes to handling rails issues on windows. unless u want to use a mac os

Comment: "dude", so what? If rails is installed, it's installed, and you can configure it yourself. You only need the installer to **install** - that's why it's called an "installer".